# How to clean pocket pH meter before storage?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, ph

[image]
Hello.

I read about different methods how to clean this specific(attached photo)pocket pH meter before storage and i can't figure out what is the right way.

One method says to stir the pH meter(glass electrode)in distilled water and
replace the protective cap,other says to stir the glass electrode only in tap water before replace the protective cap.One says also to wipe dry with cloth(or filter paper)the measuring electrode,while other says to add few drops of storage fluid in the protective cap before replace the protective cap.Those too many methods for the same type of pH meter made me confused.What should be the right way?

Comment: The right way is the one described in the official manual.

Comment: Yes,but each manual  gives different method (as i described) for the same type of ph meter and also the manual are not clear at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "*each manual*"? There should be only one official manual and the rest is something else. And thank you for removing the watermark from the image;)

Comment: This is a cheap chiness no brand ph meter,that you can't find a normal understandable manual for it and when you read the instruction of use for the same type of ph meter on different places a round the web,you get different methods.I mean,almost the same,but difference in small important things as i mentioned.

Comment: I see, now it makes sense, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem.I guess that by looking at the photo,the chemical expert here may know what should be the right way to clean and store this type of ph meter and help with that issue.

Comment: see [pH electrode storage](https://help.thermoworks.com/knowledge-base/care-maintenance-ph-meter-electrodes/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIksOT2deF5gIVov_jBx21MAfjEAAYAiAAEgLh3vD_BwE)

Comment: MaxW@I read your link,but it seems that the instruction in the link is refer to a different type of ph meters.For example:the link says to soak the ph meter in electrode storage solution or ph 4 buffer solution for hydration,while this yellow ph meter is instructed to be soaked in distilled water for hydration.Could this yellow ph meter has a special bulb electrode?